# Magento 2: How to add Estimate Shipping and Tax in Minicart?

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, mini-cart, totals

I want to add  Estimate Shipping and Tax block on Minicart. It is possible to calculate tax and shipping from minicart block?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is possible for sure but it will make a huge minicart. Anyways the question is how do you want to do it. Do you have your own theme? You want to do it with a Module?

Comment: I want to add in module

Comment: @SwAt.Be is there possible with custom modul?

Comment: Sorry for the late response , this is possible for sure but it requires some work and knowledge of the theme that you are using. I'm afraid this will involve custom work like we do for our customers but i can't give you an out of the box solution for it as far as i know. It depends how your theme uses blank inheritance or creates own blocks etc..

Comment: Can you suggest how can I do this??

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not capable of giving you this answer without researching it myself for a couple of hours. I'm sorry.

Comment: What i can say for you is that the minicart is based on minicart.js and that you will need to adjust the add-to-cart.js and the minicart.js or add your own JS that implements the action of the update cart button in ajax to your minicart and also you will need to add the block that is responsible for the totals in the cart to the container of the minicart

Comment: You can always just try to add the block of cart totals to the minicart xml and see what it does , maybe it will work out of the box

Comment: Ok let me try this